# Updating a junction table with bookshelfjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I would like to update a junction table, to add/remove appropriate records (with bookshelfjs). I thought this was possible with updatePivot, but that didn't work. Now I am just trying heavy-handed approach of deleting relevant junction records, yet that doesn't even work. Here are some snippets.

First, the table structure:

```
resources table
-(id)
-(url)

tags table
-(id)
-(name)

resource_has_tags
-(resource_id)
-(tag_id)
```

For example, A resource is associated with zero or more tags. The junction table has a record for each relationship. Specifically, Initial case (create): Create new resource (id:1), has relation to tag #100, 101.  Result: resource_has_tags table has 2 records (1 - 100, and 1 - 101).  Second case (update): resource should now be associated with tag 102, 103. resource_has_tags should be (1 - 102, 1 - 103).

The resource model file

```
tags: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany('Tag', 'resource_has_tags', 'resource_id', 'tag_id');
},


getTags: function() {
    return this.related('tags');
},

getTagsJSON: function() {
    return this.getTags().map(function(i){
        return {id: i.id, name: i.get('name')};
    });
},
```

An example of resource controller's create method (this works).

```
  'create': function(req, res) {
    var data = clean(req.body),
        tags = [],
        topics = [];

    if (data.tags) {
        tags = data.tags;
        delete data.tags;
    }

    if (data.topics) {
        topics = data.topics;
        delete data.topics;
    }


    Resource.forge(data).save()
        .then(function(model) {
            Promise.all([
                model.getTags().attach(tags),
                model.getTopics().attach(tags)
            ])
                .then(function(){
                    res.json(model);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    res.json(err);
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.json(err);
        });
```

My resource controller's update method (this does not delete or refresh the junction table).

```
    'update': function(req, res) {
    var data = clean(req.body),
        tags = [],
        topics = [];

    if (data.tags) {
        tags = data.tags;
        delete data.tags;
    }

    if (data.topics) {
        topics = data.topics;
        delete data.topics;
    }

    req.resource.save(data, {patch: 'true'})
        .then(function(model) {
            Promise.all([
                model.getTags().updatePivot()
            ])
                .then(function(){
                    res.status(204);
                    res.json();
                })
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.json(err);
        });
```

Comment: You need to use attach and detach functions of you want to do it using bookshelf functions. I believe updatePivot is used to update data in a pivot that is not the foreignkey or otherkey

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work. It's not pretty, but works. I just nuke all the entries in the junction table first, then re-attach (with new values). Not ideal, but it works. If anyone still knows the way to use updatePivot appropriately, i'd rather use that.

```
'update': function(req, res) {
    var data = clean(req.body),
        tags = [],
        topics = [];

    if (data.tags) {
        tags = data.tags;
        delete data.tags;
    }

    if (data.topics) {
        topics = data.topics;
        delete data.topics;
    }

    req.resource.save(data, {patch: 'true'})
        .then(function(model) {
            Promise.all([
                model.related('tags').detach(),
                model.getTags().attach(tags),
                model.related('topics').detach(),
                model.getTopics().attach(topics)
            ])
                .then(function(){
                    res.status(204);
                    res.json();
                })
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.json(err);
        });
```